# c++ Templates to change constness of a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I am interested in designing a template interface where the const ness of the function and return type itself changes depending on the template parameter. I have managed to do this for the return type as follows.

```
template<typename T, bool canChange>
struct Changable{};

template<typename T>
struct Changable<T,true>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Changable<T,false>
{
    typedef const T type;
};

template<typename T, bool canChange>
struct Data{
    typedef typename Changable<T,canChange>::type DataType;        
    DataType m_data; //< This makes it const/non-const at compile time.

    // This function will also make the return type const/non-const 
    // at compile time. 
    DataType& GetDataRef(){ return m_data;} 

    //However, it seems to me that I still need a second function 
    //with an explicit "const", which I can't seem to avoid.
    DataType& GetDataRef()const{return m_data;}
};
```

Can I somehow avoid having two const/non-const functions here at compile time using some SFINAE magic? std::enable_if would have been ideal here but it seems to me that const is not a type and that approach may not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not keep only the `const` version if you don't need to overload?

Comment: @KABoissonneault I do need both the versions, since the constness of the template will change depending on the template parameter. Just to clarify, I do want to be able to create certain `Data` structs which can be modified at a later stage, while some are guaranteed to not change. Hence the need for both const/non-const functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example based on inheritance:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, bool canChange>
struct Changable { using type = const T; };

template<typename T> 
struct Changable<T, true> { using type = std::decay_t<T>; };

template<typename, typename, bool>
struct Base;

template<typename D, typename T>
struct Base<D, T, true> {
    using DataType = typename Changable<T, true>::type;
    DataType& GetDataRef() { std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl; return static_cast<D*>(this)->m_data; }
};

template<typename D, typename T>
struct Base<D, T, false> {
    using DataType = typename Changable<T, false>::type;
    DataType& GetDataRef() const { std::cout << "const" << std::endl; return static_cast<const D*>(this)->m_data; }
};

template<typename T, bool canChange>
struct Data: Base<Data<T, canChange>, T, canChange> {
    friend class Base<Data<T, canChange>, T, canChange>;
    typename Base<Data<T, canChange>, T, canChange>::DataType m_data{};
    using Base<Data<T, canChange>, T, canChange>::GetDataRef;
};

int main() {
    Data<int, true> d1;
    Data<int, false> d2;
    d1.GetDataRef();
    d2.GetDataRef();
}
```

As requested, `Data` has only one definition of the `GetDataRef` method.
Which one is available, the `const` one or the other one, depends on the value of `canChange`.

Note the `friend` declaration. It allows the base class to access to the private data members of `Data`.

Comment: Nice one! As always unbeatable! :)

Comment: @W.F. To be honest, your answer pointed the right way out. ;-)

Comment: This I like :). Thanks !

Comment: @cplusplusrat You are welcome. Challenges are always good for I usually learn something from them. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack no need for inheritance. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd approach this using the templates already available in the standard library. It does not require inheritance or any custom classes.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, bool canChange>
struct Data{
    using value_type = T;
    using cv_type = std::conditional_t<canChange, value_type, std::add_const_t<value_type>>;
    using reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<cv_type>;
    using const_reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<cv_type>>;

    Data(T t) : m_data(std::move(t)) {}

    cv_type m_data; //< This makes it const/non-const at compile time.

    // This function will also make the return type const/non-const
    // at compile time.
    reference GetDataRef(){ return m_data;}

    //However, it seems to me that I still need a second function
    //with an explicit "const", which I can't seem to avoid.
    const_reference GetDataRef() const {return m_data;}
};

int main()
{
    Data<int, true> d1 { 10 };
    d1.m_data = 12;
    const Data<int, true>& rd1 = d1;

    auto& a = d1.GetDataRef();
    auto& b = rd1.GetDataRef();
    a = 12;  // compiles fine
//    b= 12; won't compile

    Data<int, false> d2 { 10 };
    const Data<int, false>& rd2 = d2;

    auto& c = d2.GetDataRef();
    auto& d = rd2.GetDataRef();
//    c = 12;  // won't compile
//    d = 12;  // won't compile

}
```

Now to the question:

> Can I somehow avoid having two const/non-const functions here at compile time **using some SFINAE magic**?

You're almost answering your own question here. SFINAE requires that template arguments are considered in immediate context. Which is a complex way of saying that the expression in `std::enable_if<>` must depend on some template type.

Unhappily, the template type of T is known by the time the function `GetDataRef` is evaluated, so enable_if won't help us here.

So if we only want one version of `GetDataRef` we would indeed have to resort to derivation from a template type (the base class would then be evaluated in immediate context of T).

However, there is a problem even then.

consider:

- `Data<int, true>& x` This is a reference to mutable container containing mutable data
- `const Data<int, true>& y` This is a reference to an immutable container containing mutable data

calling `x.GetDataRef()` ought to return a mutable reference to an int, otherwise we'll confuse our users.

calling `y.GetDataRef()` should certainly return a const reference to an int, otherwise again, users may be shocked to learn that a member of a const thing is actually mutable.

Comment: Chapeau... anyway, the OP wants only one function in its interface, either const or non-const (it depends on `canChange`). This way, you have two definitions of `GetDataRef`. (To be clear, I agree with you that this is the way, but I don't know what the real problem is, so I cannot judge).

Comment: @skypjack I know he thinks he wants that, but I don't think he's thought it through. Answer updated.

Comment: ... _I know he thinks he wants that_ ... You win!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can solve the issue:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, bool canChange>
struct Changable: std::false_type { using type = const T; };

template<typename T>
struct Changable<T, true>: std::true_type { using type = std::decay_t<T>; };

template<typename T, bool canChange>
struct Data {
    using DataTraits = Changable<T, canChange>;

private:
    template<typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<U::value, typename U::type&>
    GetDataRefImpl() { std::cout << "non const" << std::endl; return m_data; }

    template<typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<not U::value, typename U::type&>
    GetDataRefImpl() const { std::cout << "const" << std::endl; return m_data; }

public:
    typename DataTraits::type m_data{};

    typename DataTraits::type& GetDataRef() { return GetDataRefImpl<DataTraits>(); }
    typename DataTraits::type& GetDataRef() const { return GetDataRefImpl<DataTraits>(); }
};

int main() {
    Data<int, true> d1;
    Data<int, false> d2;
    d1.GetDataRef();
    d2.GetDataRef();
}
```

The basic idea is to have both the functions exposed by the class, then forward them internally to the same *sfinae*d one that is `const` or `non-const` (this depends on the value of `canChange`).
As you can see by running the example, the result is:

> non const
>   const

This is true even if both `d1` and `d2` have been defined as non const.
The `std::enable_if` turn on the right internal function at compile time.

Note that I've used what the C++14 offers (as an example `std::enable_if_t`).
The example can be easily converted to a C++11 based on (`std::enable_if_t` is nothing more than `typename std::enable_if<condition, type>::type` and so on).

Comment: You still needed a const and non-const function in the public interface. Its only marginally better than what I already have. I have been trawling SO for similar questions and I am now increasingly convinced it can't be done without two functions in the public interface.

Comment: @cplusplusrat You are right, but those methods are nothing more than forwarder for the internal *sfinae*d method. Moreover, they let you use that method with both const and non const instances. *Constness* of your class is preserved now. Another solution would be to specialize the class on a per-`canChange` base or to have a delegate to which to forward the request.

Answer (score 1):

If C++17 is available to you, have a look at `is_const`, `add_const` and `remove_const`.
Together with `if constexpr ()`, a rather elegant solution should be possible.